# What is the reason of hidding comments and links in node.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming

What is the reason of first hiding the `comments` and `links` and later showing theme in `node.tpl.php`?

even if I delete following three lines of this system it does not change anything,
`hide($content['comments']);`
`hide($content['links']);`
`<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>`

*from node.tpl.php*

```
    <div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
            <?php
              // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
              hide($content['comments']);
              hide($content['links']);
              print render($content);
            ?>
          </div>

          <?php
            // Remove the "Add new comment" link on the teaser page or if the comment
            // form is being displayed on the same page.
            if ($teaser || !empty($content['comments']['comment_form'])) {
              unset($content['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);
            }
            // Only display the wrapper div if there are links.
            $links = render($content['links']);
            if ($links):
          ?>
            <div class="link-wrapper">
              <?php print $links; ?>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>

          <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove them from your node.tpl.php -- but that is always an option.

I recommend a better solution, however.

First, you can check out [this resource](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/nodes-content-types-and-fields/specify-how-fields-are-displayed) to read more about how to deal with fields when they are being displayed on a node.

A really good solution (and one I always recommend) is using modules like [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) to customize the fields on your content type. You can customize the create/edit form as well as you can control which fields you want to be visible when visitors are looking at nodes.

Comment: There is not a question of using other things(i.e. DS), everything works fine, but what is the reason of hiding. I guess they are hiding because, something is not happening the way they want, I am not sure. Hence, I would like to understand that. Thanks

Comment: Oh, you want to know why in this exact three line instance is there. This is a hold over from (I think!) from Drupal 5 when the entity system started to appear for Drupal 6. Essentially, in order to make that happen and let the field system in Drupal 6 work its magic, the theme engine needed to change to support it. It might not be required anymore. If you are really interested to find out why, I would go backwards in the commit log to see when that entry was added and see what other commits around the same time. But overall, the other answers here address what alternatives to use.

Comment: I think, I got the answer in your comment. So, to acquire new system in Drupal, they had to do some Surgery and this hiding is result of that. I think you can just update your answer with this information and I will accept.

Answer (score 1):

The reason they are hidden and then re-displayed is because it gives more granular control over their placement.

Removing those three lines may not seem to do anything. But for them to do something some conditions have to be met: Links and comments have to be present and populated. This means that comments has to be enabled on the node or that something is hooking into the node links and adding links based on display mode, etc. One of these places is on a teaser view mode, you'll see a "Read more" link.

Also, content_extra_fields is a module that I like for simple placement of the links and comments using the field_ui.

Comment: I would like to understand that granular control, and why it is arising here? Due to which abnormality or problem, it is arising? Thanks for answer though, appreciated.

Comment: I think it could be arising because link and comments are always supposed to be last in the views of Drupal. But using a preprocess_node or hook_node_view() you can add arrays and variables to the content array. Moving comments and links below all of content allows for the additional variables/arrays/markup to show with the top content and fields, but not have a weight race with comments and links.